# Machinery optimization problem

Tags: optimization, constraints

My math skills are not nearly what you guys possess, but I am willing to work at this if you can help me.  Here's my problem; it is optimizing the supply against known demand:

### Supply:

```
machine 1:  10 products per month   (we have 5 of these machines)  =  50 per month capacity
machine 2:  20 products per month   (we have 20 of these machines) = 400 per month capacity
machine 3:   4 products per month   (we have 10 of these machines) =  40 per month capacity
```

### Demand:

```
Product batch a:  size=1,000   due-date=  month 7
Product batch b:  size=2,000   due-date=  month 4
Product batch c:  size=1,200   due-date=  month 5
```

Assume we start at month 1, so something due month 7 has 7 full months of process time.
Assume no penalty for completing a batch before the due date.
Assume machines are fungible and batch can be run on multiple machines types.

Need to back-solve for **optimal start month for each product batch**, and show where we are short capacity and need more machines.  I can do it manually by making start/end month the same, then "pulling" each project start month backward and try to smooth the demand to fit within capacity, but once I get over a few batches in the pipeline, it becomes untenable.

Would like to figure out an algorithm or equation that I can put into MS Excel to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to compare the cumulative amount needed at each month with the amount you can produce.  At month $4$ you need $2000$, but can only produce $490$ per month for a total $1960$.  You are short $40$.  At month $5$ you need $3200$ and can only produce $2450$ so you are short $750$  At month $7$, you need $4200$ and can only produce $3430$ so are short $770$  Your biggest shortfall per month is the month $5$ one, so you need an additional $150$ per month production capacity.

Comment: ok, thanks I didn't realize it was that simple, I though I had to somehow figure out when the batches should be started, to "level out" the usage of the machinery.

Comment: You said there was no penalty for having a batch early, so you might as well start building day 1